# Save as draft two fields with one name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How i can save as draft two inputs fields which assigned with one object field. I use sisyphus-rails gem. But they save only last field with one name.

```
 = f.input :owners, as: :select, multiple: true,
       collection: current_organization.actors_with_customer_access
 = f.input :owners, as: :select, multiple: true,
      collection: current_organization.actors_with_only_write_access
```

Answer (score 0):

When `form_for ... do |f|` it use single instance of your model in `f` variable. If you want to use multiple form, maybe you find useful [official rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object), or even [unofficial russian rails docs](http://rusrails.ru/rails-form-helpers#privyazyvanie-formy-k-ob-ektu)